# QDomDocument: How do I get text from a br element?

Tags: html, c++, qt

I'm using Qt::QDomDocument to parse html. Here is the simple code:

```
        QDomDocument doc("doc");
        QByteArray data = "<div><br />&ldquo;Of course, Jason. My thoughts, exactly.&rdquo;<br /></div>";

        QString sErrorMsg;
        int errLine, errCol;

        if (!doc.setContent(data, &sErrorMsg, &errLine, &errCol)) {
            qDebug() << sErrorMsg;
            qDebug() << errLine << ":" << errCol;
            return;
        }

        QDomNodeList nodeList = doc.elementsByTagName("br");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); ++i) {
            qDebug() << nodeList.at(i).toDocument().toString();
        }
```

`nodeList.at(i)` always returns empty string. And I tried another approach:

```
        auto child = doc.firstChild();
        while (!child.isNull())
        {
            qDebug() << child.toDocument().toString();
            child = child.nextSibling();
        }
```

Also didn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT, but you need to get the text from the text node after the br, not from the br itself.

Comment: The br element is empty and has no text

Comment: @MrLister, So I tried `auto child = doc.firstChild();` but also didn't work.

Comment: Is `doc.firstChild` not the outer div? Also, I don't know what `toString()` of a Document outputs, but you may want to look for something like `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: @MrLister, Thanks remind. I'll check.

Comment: @MrLister, `auto child = doc.firstChild().firstChild();` does better. There are 5 empty strings outputed.

Comment: @MrLister, I think this is the correct direction. I'll figure it out.
`qDebug() << child.nodeName();`
"br"
"ldquo"
"#text"
"rdquo"
"br"


Press any key to continue . . .